Finite difference scheme for solving 3D stationary diffusion equation in inhomogeneous medium using spatially irregular orthogonal discretisation grid
I try to numerically solve the 3D stationary diffusion equation in a medium with spatially inhomogeneous conduction.
Analytical problem
In the context of this post, heat diffusion is considered. The analytical problem is described by
$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{j}
$$
where $Q$ is the diffusing energy and $\vec{j}$ is the energy current given by
$$
\vec{j} = -\lambda\vec{\nabla}T
$$
where $\lambda$ is the linear thermal conductivity of the medium and $T$ is the temperature. The stationary equation yields
\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\lambda\vec{\nabla}T)
&= \mathbb{\vec{\nabla}}\lambda\cdot\vec{\nabla}T + \lambda\thinspace\nabla^2T\\
&=\sum_{i=\{x,y,z\}} \partial_i\lambda\thinspace\partial_iT+\lambda\thinspace\partial_i^2T\\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Space discretization and minimal example
In the picture below, the intersection between each black thin line of the 3-dimensional and orthogonal grid represents a $T$ point. The $\lambda$ values are found between each pair of neighboring $T$ at equal distance. The blue cube has a different $\lambda$ value than space around it. The yellow and dark blue diamond-shaped points are respectively fixed at different $T$ value (Dirichlet boundary conditions). This means that in this example, points storing $T$ values that are not boundary conditions are found at the 8 corners of the cube. Due to the symmetry of the problem, 4 of them (yellow) will yield a common $T$ value after solving the equation system and the 4 others (dark blue) will yield another common value.

Finite difference
The finite difference (f.d) linear system can be written for each $(k_x,k_y,k_z)$ points that store a $T$ value which is not a boundary condition as
$$\sum_{i=\{x,y,z\}}\underbrace{\underbrace{\frac{\lambda_{k_i+1/2}-\lambda_{k_i-1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i+1}+\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i-1}}}_{\text{f.d. of }\partial_i\lambda}\underbrace{\frac{T_{k_i+1}-T_{k_i-1}}{D_{k_i+1}+D_{k_i-1}}}_{\text{f.d. of }\partial_iT}}_{\text{term (1)}}+\underbrace{\bar\lambda_{(k_x,k_y,k_z)}\underbrace{\frac{\frac{T_{k_i+1}-T_{k_i}}{D_{k_i+1}}-\frac{T_{k_i}-T_{k_i-1}}{D_{k_i-1}}}{\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i+1}+\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i-1}}}_{\text{f.d. of }\partial_i^2T}}_{\text{term (2)}}=0$$
where
$$
\bar\lambda_{(k_x,k_y,k_z)} = \frac{\sum_{i=\{x,y,z\}}\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i-1}\lambda_{k_i-1/2}+\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i+1}\lambda_{k_i+1/2}}{\sum_{i=\{x,y,z\}}\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i-1}+\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i+1}}
$$
is the mean conductivity evaluated at the point $(k_x,k_y,k_z)$, the subscript of $T$ are its index along a given dimension in the model, the $\lambda_{k_i\pm1/2}$ are located between $T_{k_i}$ and $T_{k_i\pm1}$ and the distance $D_{k_i\pm 1}$ is the distance lying between $T_{k_i}$ and $T_{k_i\pm 1}$ (see picture below).

Writing subscript in this way may be an abuse of notation, but it does help to lighten it. For instance, the notation $T_{k_i\pm1}$ in the sum over $i$ means that $T$ is evaluated at $(k_x,k_y,k_z)\pm \vec{e_i}^T$.
This equation can be reduced to
$$\sum_{i=\{x,y,z\}}\left(-\frac{\lambda_{k_i+1/2}-\lambda_{k_i-1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}(D_{k_i+1}+D_{k_i-1})^2}+\frac{\bar\lambda_{(k_x,k_y,k_z)}}{\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i-1}(D_{k_i-1}+D_{k_i+1})}\right)T_{k_i-1}+\left(\frac{\lambda_{k_i+1/2}-\lambda_{k_i-1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}(D_{k_i+1}+D_{k_i-1})^2}+\frac{\bar\lambda_{(k_x,k_y,k_z)}}{\frac{1}{2}D_{k_i+1}(D_{k_i-1}+D_{k_i+1})}\right)T_{k_i+1}+\frac{\bar\lambda_{(k_x,k_y,k_z)}}{\frac{1}{2}(D_{k_i-1}+D_{k_i+1})}\left(\frac{1}{D_{k_i-1}}+\frac{1}{D_{k_i+1}}\right)T_{k_i} = 0.$$
The problem is then solved with a linear solver.
Results
The algorithm has been tested by hand and with a script for the simple case described above and yields the same results for both. It does not give the correct results for both an irregular grid and an inhomogeneous medium at the same time. However, it works for a regular grid (i.e. $D_{k_i}\equiv D\thinspace \forall k, i $) with an inhomogeneous medium or when the conduction is homogeneous (i.e. $\lambda_{k_i}\equiv \lambda\thinspace \forall k, i $) with an irregular grid. This last points means that the finite differences for term (2) (Laplacian term) are correct to within one multiplicative constant. The first point might come from a problem with the division by the spatial distances and explain the multiplicative constant that unbalance the first and second term of the equation (respectively). It does not seem that the evaluation of $\bar\lambda$ is the problem since the finite difference scheme gave the correct results for different $\lambda$ inside (rather on) the cube than outside the cube when the grid was homogeneously spaced, but this assertion might be wrong.
Question
Where is the error in the finite difference equation system ? How are both term(1) and term(2) unbalanced ?

It is better to leave the equation as:
$$
\nabla\cdot(\lambda\nabla T) = 0
$$
Indeed, $\nabla\lambda$ lies on vertices while $\nabla T$ lies on the edge, so it is not obvious how to multiply them. Similarly $\lambda$ lies on the edge while $\nabla^2T$ lies on the vertices, so again, the product is not natural. Before tackling the 3D case, you can start by looking at the 1D case.
1D
You can discretise your gradient as:
$$
(\partial_xT)_{k+1/2} = \frac{T_{k+1}-T_i}{x_{k+1}-x_k}
$$
Your current is therefore:
$$
j_{k+1/2} = -\lambda_{k+1/2} \frac{T_{k+1}-T_i}{x_{k+1}-x_k}
$$
You can recognise $\frac{\lambda_{k+1/2}}{x_{k+1}-x_k}$ as a conductance. Physically, your discrete grid is just conductors in series. Their different conductances scale specifically to recover a nice continuous limit. You get the stationary state by applying Kirchoff's law of currents:
$$
j_{k+1/2} - j_{k-1/2} = 0
$$
For the heat equation, you need to rescale the LHS to recover the divergence in the continuous limit:
$$
\begin{align}
[\partial_x(\lambda\partial_xT)]_k &= -\frac{j_{k+1/2}-j_{k-1/2}}{x_{k+1/2}-x_{k-1/2}}\\
&= \frac{\lambda_{k+1/2}}{(x_{k+1/2}-x_{k-1/2})(x_{k+1}-x_k)}T_{k+1}+\frac{\lambda_{k-1/2}}{(x_{k+1/2}-x_{k-1/2})(x_k-x_{k-1})}T_{k-1}-\frac1{x_{k+1/2}-x_{k-1/2}}\left(\frac{\lambda_{k+1/2}}{x_{k+1}-x_k}-\frac{\lambda_{k-1/2}}{x_k-x_{k-1}}\right)T_k
\end{align}
$$
where I used:
$$
x_{k+1/2} = \frac{x_{k+1}+x_k}2
$$
This is why I would rather introduce:
$$
D_{k+1/2} = x_{k+1}-x_k \quad D_k = x_{k-1/2}-x_{k+1/2} = \frac{x_{k+1}-x_{k-1}}2
$$
The equation is more compactly:
$$
\begin{align}
[\partial_x(\lambda\partial_xT)]_k &= \frac{\lambda_{k+1/2}}{D_kD_{k+1/2}}T_{k+1}+\frac{\lambda_{k-1/2}}{D_kD_{k-1/2}}T_{k-1}-\frac1{D_k}\left(\frac{\lambda_{k+1/2}}{D_{k+1/2}}-\frac{\lambda_{k-1/2}}{D_{k-1/2}}\right)T_k
\end{align}
$$
This scheme works inhomogeneous and irregular spacing.
3D
From there, it is easy to generalise in higher dimensions. Guided by the physical insight, you can imagine your medium being a mesh of conductances. Conductance scales as:
$$
G= \lambda \frac{A}{L}
$$
with $L$ the length of the conductor and $A$ its cross section area. Let $e_x,e_y,e_z$ be the directions to nearest neighbours. You therefore need three types of quantities:

$D_{k+e_i/2} = |x_{k+e_i}-x_k|$: the distance to the neighbour
$A_{k+e_i/2} = \prod_{j\neq i}\frac{|x_{k+e_j}-x_{k-e_j}|}2$: the area of the face separating the nearest neighbour
$V_k = \prod_i\frac{|x_{k+e_i}-x_{k-e_i}|}2$: the volume around the vertex (analogue of $D_k$ in 1D)

Thus, conductance of each edge is therefore:
$$
G_{k+e_i/2} = \lambda_{k+e_i/2}\frac{A_{k+e_i/2}}{D_{k+e_i/2}}
$$
and the stationary state is given by Kirchhoff's law:
$$
\sum_i\sum_\pm\lambda_{k\pm e_i/2}\frac{A_{k\pm e_i/2}}{D_{k\pm e_i/2}}(T_{k\pm e_i}-T_k) = 0
$$
Rescaling to recover the divergence in the continuum limit gives:
$$
\begin{align}
[\nabla\cdot(\lambda\nabla T)]_k = \frac1{V_k}\sum_i\sum_\pm\lambda_{k\pm e_i/2}\frac{A_{k\pm e_i/2}}{D_{k\pm e_i/2}}(T_{k\pm e_i}-T_k)
\end{align}
$$
In your case, since $A_{k+e_i/2} = A_{k-e_i/2}$, you just need to introduce:
$$
D_k^{(i)} = \frac{V_k}{A_{k\pm e_i/2}}
$$
which is the analogue of $D_k$ in 1D and get:
$$
\begin{align}
[\nabla\cdot(\lambda\nabla T)]_k = \sum_i\sum_\pm\frac{\lambda_{k\pm e_i/2}}{D_k^{(i)}D_{k\pm e_i/2}}T_{k\pm e_i}-\left(\sum_i\sum_\pm\frac{\lambda_{k\pm e_i/2}}{D_k^{(i)}D_{k\pm e_i/2}}\right)T_k
\end{align}
$$

The numerical implementation of what you described works. To put in in simple terms, it is innapropriate to solve the local form of a differential equation when the volume elements are not infinitesimal (the volume storing $T$ values indeed have a volume). It is required to average this local equation over the volume elements. To do so for each volume element, the local equation must be integrated the volume element and then divided by its volume.
What I did was similar to consider complete void between the edges which would analogically give a model looking like a toothpick construction.

Not quite. Actually, you need both the toothpick view and the "fleshy" view. If you imagine your temperature lying in cells, then there is no distance between the cells $D_{k+e_i/2}$. Indeed, when computing $\nabla T$, you use the toothpick view with edges, but when you take the divergence, you use the "fleshy" view with faces.

The general approach to this is Hodge duality, and allows you to juggle between the lattice and its dual (vertices $\leftrightarrow$ cells, edges $\leftrightarrow$ faces). While it is not fully consistent to have both views in the discrete setting (unless you add some gaps), everything makes sense in the continuum limit.

I was thinking about the value of G_k+ei/2 in the case were the corresponding edge lies along the border between two different media. (1) The conductance G_k+ei/2 would become a composition of the lambda of both media ? (2) Or instead, should we never face this situation but rather have a grid that contains edges that crosses normally the interface between different media ? (but never lies in the interface plane) In this case, the A*lambda in G would be weighted by the inverse distance to the interface.
